# sqlalchemy query : get list of posts ordered_by no. of likes and comments

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying create a get API returns list of posts which should be ordered by no. of likes and comments including posts without comments or likes. I'm Stuck in the query. If break it into subquery like below

***queryset***

```
week  = datetime.timedelta(7)
today = datetime.date.today()
most_commented_posts = db.session.query(Post).join(Comment).group_by(Post.id).order_by(func.count().desc()).filter(Post.created_at>=(today-week)).all()
```

I get list of posts ordered by most commented posts ***but it skips posts with no comments***
Below is my model
***model***

```
class Base(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id               = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title            = db.Column(db.String(255))
    discription      = db.Column(db.String)
    image            = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="cascade"))
    comments         = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
    Likes            = db.relationship('PostLikes', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')  
    user             = db.relationship('User', backref='user', lazy=True)

class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'

    id               = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text             = db.Column(db.String)
    user_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="cascade"))
    post_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id", ondelete="cascade"))
    user             = db.relationship('User', backref='comment', lazy=True)

class PostLikes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post_likes'

    id               = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id", ondelete="cascade"))
    user_id          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id", ondelete="cascade"))
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use `.outerjoin(Comment)`

By default the `JOIN` statement performs an `INNER JOIN` which leaves out any missing rows. If you perform an `OUTER JOIN` missing rows will be "filled in" with `NULLs`.